# Is it possible to use a fold with a Vec?

Tags: iterator, rust, fold

I was thinking about how to implement Fibonacci in Rust, and thought I could do it with a `fold`.

What I came up with is the following:

```rust
// Editor's note: this code sample predates Rust 1.0 and 
// is not valid syntax. The concepts remain valid.

range(2, generations).fold(vec![1u, 1], |data: &mut Vec<uint>, value| {
    data.push(data[-2] + data[-1]);

    data
}).last()
```

However, this does not compile because I can't get `data` into the `fold` in a way the borrow checker likes. Either it is immutable, or it is borrowed multiple times or then the last `data` is out of scope and I can't return `data` to `fold`.

Is there a way to use fold with a `Vec`? Or do I have to resort to to a loop?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's [a working version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0e9ca90652f9bef275700a597f56d1e0):

```
fn main() {
    let z = (2..12).fold(vec![1u64, 1], |mut data, _| {
        data.push(data[data.len() - 2] + data[data.len() - 1]);
        data
    });
    println!("{:?}", z.last())
}
```

There are a few problems with your approach:

1. `data: &mut Vec<uint>` (or `usize` in modern Rust) — Your accumulator variable isn't a "reference to a mutable vector", it's just a "mutable vector".
2. `data[-2]` — Rust doesn't implicitly index from the back of the array for negative values. In fact, the index doesn't even accept negative values! It wants a `usize`, so your `-2` and `-1` would have become very large numbers!

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! Though I have a question then (regarding your point 1): I added the ref because I thought that data inside the closure would then be a copy of the data vector, and not point to the same data vector. How does Rust decide when to pass a value by reference and when by value?

Comment: Rust doesn't "decide" anything for you; it's all up to the programmer. [`fold`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IteratorExt.html#tymethod.fold) accepts an initial value of type `B` and a function that takes a `B` and a single iterator value and returns a `B`. In this case, your `B` is a `Vec<u64>`.

Comment: Also note that your closure doesn't *capture* any variables from its context, it's simply working on arguments provided to the closure. The closure could be Fn, FnOnce, or FnMut, all of which are variants on how the closure captures its environment.

Comment: I see where my thinking went wrong now. Thanks a log! I thought that not using a ref would move the vector out of the `fold`. But I guess it gets moved backed at the end of the closure, that's why it works.